# How can we sync different databases and application in django

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-rest-framework, postgis

How can we access other database tables into django application database. Here 'default' database is main application and 'cl_db' is other application which is developed in asp.net but using same database server here how can we sync 'cl_db' database into 'default' database.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2', 
            'NAME': 'fail_over',                    
            'USER': 'SomeUser',                      
            'PASSWORD': 'SomePassword',                  
            'HOST': '127.0.0.1',                     
            'PORT': '',                      
    },

    'cl_db': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2', 
            'NAME': 'cl_dev',                    
            'USER': 'SomeUser',                      
            'PASSWORD': 'SomePassword',                 
            'HOST': '127.0.0.1',                     
            'PORT': '',                      
    },
}
```

```
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['app.dbrouters.AuthRounter']
```

```
class AuthRouter:
    """
    A router to control all database operations on models in the
    auth and contenttypes applications.
    """
    route_app_labels = {'auth', 'contenttypes'}

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        """
        Attempts to read auth and contenttypes models go to auth_db.
        """
        if model._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels:
            return 'default'
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        """
        Attempts to write auth and contenttypes models go to auth_db.
        """
        if model._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels:
            return 'default'
        return None

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        """
        Allow relations if a model in the auth or contenttypes apps is
        involved.
        """
        if (
            obj1._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels or
            obj2._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels
        ):
           return True
        return None

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        """
        Make sure the auth and contenttypes apps only appear in the
        'auth_db' database.
        """
        if app_label in self.route_app_labels:
            return db == 'default'
        return None
```

models.py

```
class usermaster(models.Model):
  userid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
  class Meta:
    app_label = 'user_master'
```

Comment: you have to create a database router which tell Django which database use for app or model

Comment: can I get reference I did research on routers but it is not working @TanveerAhmad

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/multi-db/
there for you just implement if you found any error or got stuck in any problem let me know

Comment: I followed same document but it is sync to cl_db but I need cl_db sync to default db

Comment: can you give me an example how you are using

Comment: I updated code check once@TanveerAhmad

Comment: you have to use master slave relationship if you want cl_db snync to default db

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251963/discussion-between-vas-and-tanveer-ahmad).